# Development on a single VF and apex class

Tags: org

I don't whether this question should be posted here, because this is related to dev process not any issue with salesforce. My issue is: we 3 are working in a same org, i.e: 2 guys are working on a same VF page at a same time and i am working on apex code. other 2 may have same requirement to add some code to apex class also. As we know that this process will overwrite each other code. So we have created 3 clones of VF and apex class, then we work on it and after compare we update it. If I go with eclips to this may overwrite each other code. Is their any effective way to over come this issue. Please guide us to fix this issue. We cant assign a single whole work to a person because their is lot of work to do.

Comment: If this single page is complicated, you might well find that using a [thin-controller](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89043/salesforce-code-review-best-practices-for-controllers/89046#89046) approach improves the code and has the side effect of allowing the 3 people to work on separate files. Perhaps apex:components could achieve the same result for the page content.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether we are following the best approach or not. But as in a team of many developers working on the same package of code we are basically following this:

We used [trialforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/). Each developer has its own trialforce org and github branch. So basically each developer is working on an independent org and commit into an independent branch. We merge into a main branch and resolve conflicts there. For deployment, we are using Circle CI. But I am pretty sure a bunch of other deployment tools can do the same thing - Jenkins, Gearset, etc.

Hope this helps.